# Use REPLACE statement to change data in ALL fields of the result set

Tags: sql, database, replace, syntax, data-manipulation

Basically, the subject. I'm accessing a database via **Web interface**, which submits `SQL` queries using a Web form. The database is in **read-only** mode, so I cannot use `UPDATE` statement. Also, please note that I need to act on **all fields** at once. Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE((SELECT * FROM sf0314.groups), ':', ';')
FROM sf0314.groups
WHERE group_id < 1000
```

Server replied with the following error message:

> There was an error in your query: subquery must return only one column

I also tried to use `AS` to refer to all fields in the main `SELECT`, but it was unsuccessful as well. I understand how I can use `REPLACE` to update one or several **named fields** in the result set. But, the question is:

**How can I refer to multiple (all) fields in the REPLACE statement? Thank you!**

Comment: You can do it. But you need to use dynamic sql. Here is an example for update: http://alexduggleby.com/2008/05/09/off-topic-t-sql-replace-all-occurrences-in-all-columns-in-all-tables/

Comment: Where did the second answer (with `concat` solution) go? It just disappeared!

Comment: Poster deleted it I suspect

Comment: @PeterRing: Thank you! When you say "dynamic SQL", I assume you mean stored procedures or UDFs. Am I correct?

Comment: @Fred: Thank you! I liked the `concat` solution, hope the poster will come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. REPLACE() function accepts three string arguments, but can't accept lists or resultsets.
You have to list all of your columns in the select statement, then add REPLACE function to each column.

**Example**

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(field1, ':', ';') AS field1
    REPLACE(field2, ':', ';') AS field2,
    REPLACE(field3, ':', ';') AS field3,
    REPLACE(field4, ':', ';') AS field4,
FROM
    YourTable
```

**EDIT** (Summarizing the conversation in the comments)

You can generate your field list using the metadata storage provided by the RDBMS. In most Database Engines, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA contains the metadata:

*Example for MySQL:*

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('REPLACE(`', C.COLUMN_NAME, '`, '':'', '';'')')
FROM
    information_schema.COLUMNS C
WHERE
    C.TABLE_SCHEMA = '[YourDatabaseName]'
    AND C.TABLE_NAME = '[YourTableName]'
```

*Example for MSSQL (using DMVs):*

```
USE [YourDatabaseName];

SELECT
    'REPLACE([' + C.name + '], '':'', '';'')'
FROM
    sys.columns C
WHERE
    C.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[schema].[table]')
```

Comment: Appreciate your fast reply! I know the standard syntax, but I thought that there is a way to generically refer to all fields, such as using subqueries or aliases.

Comment: You are welcome! I don't know any kind of generic syntax for this. When I encounter similar problems, I usually generate the select statement or at least the field list. You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA and its tables to get the list of the columns (in MySQL) or system views (dmv) in T-SQL, or Oracle's system views (or whatever they call it :))

Comment: Yes, I've seen here on SO a solution that auto-iterates through fields via the schema table(s), but I'm not sure, if I have access to that. The system provides access only through Web interface :-(. So, if I have credentials to read system tables and will be able to find their names, then MAYBE I'd be able to use this approach. I really liked the `concat` solution that somebody suggested, but after several minutes the answer disappeared. The author probably deleted it, realizing it won't work. Strange, because I found similar solution here on SO...

Comment: If you can read the tables, in most rdbms you can read the metadata tables (aka system tables). They will contain only those table's information what you can use. INFORMATION_SCHEMA's implementation in most RDMS is based on views, which are dynamically filters their data based on the current user's permission. Give it a try: `SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` in MySQL

Comment: Great! I was successful in executing the query that you suggested. But, it generated tons of information. I'll try to make sense of it. I need to double check, maybe I can avoid using REPLACE at all. Regardless of that, your suggestion is valuable.

Comment: I've just edited the original answer to cover the information provided in the comments. Also I've added some examples.